# Pycharm doesn't recognise Sqoop libraries

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, hadoop, sqoop

I am on Pycharm trying to use Sqoop import job to load MySQL data in to HDFS.
I downloaded this package on terminal

```
pip install pysqoop
```

I tried running this package

```
from pysqoop.SqoopImport import Sqoop  
sqoop = Sqoop(help=True)  
code = sqoop.perform_import()
```

This was the error

```
/home/amel/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/bin/python /home/amel/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/Hello.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/amel/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/Hello.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pysqoop.SqoopImport import Sqoop ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pysqoop'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Do you have your `venv` activated when running `pip install pysqoop`? If not then run `./venv/bin/activate` first.

Comment: Thank you so much. After activating it, and re-installing pysqoop, It worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option that your python code is running in a different python environment than your main one go to pycharm file->settings->project->project-interpreter. Than change your env.

OR

put your cursor on pysqoop and press alt+enter and choose "install package pysqoop"